# Is it possible to stop slick slider from autoplay within a google tag manager tag?

Tags: google-tag-manager, slick.js

I am wondering if it is possible to stop a slick slider from autoplay with a tag in google tag manager because the `.slick` is not accessible. I'll hope someone could clear this out for me :)

I am working on a site where I need to ab test and want to stop the slick slider from autoplay, but I don't think the slick instance accessible from this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GTM you have access to DOM, for example via Cutom HTML tag so you can definitely change anything within the page. (Useful Link to google support pages: [here](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103657?hl=en))

To do this you can create a new Custom HTML Tag:

```
<script>
$('.yourAutoplaySlickElement').slick("slickPause"); 
</script>
```

Just make sure this tag is triggered after your slick element was initialized.

Comment: this:    $('.slick-slider').slick("slickPause"); doesn't pause the autoplay

Comment: I don't get the instance of slick

Comment: It seems that the instance isn't init because when I run the init event with a console.log in that function it is not logging

Comment: Then you have a completely differnt problem to what you described in the question. Can you maybe post some code showing how you setup the slick slider?